# Symfony Folder Structure Standard

Tags: symfony

Is there someone who can explain in detail the standard used by Symfony* to name folders and files in the directory structure?

```
MyBundle
├─ Controller/                 <-- 1) why singular?
├─ Model/                      <-- 2) why singular?
├─ Resources/                  <-- 3) why plural?
│  ├─ config/                  <-- 4) why the "c" is lowercase?
│  ├─ translations/
│  ├─ views/                   <-- 5) why the "v" is lowercase and views is plural?
│  │  └─ Default/              <-- 6) Why uppercase?
│  │     └─ my_view.html.twig  <-- 7) Why lowercase and snake case?
│  └─ public/
├─ Service/                    <-- 8) why singular?
└─ Tests/
```

This leads to another question: if I want to create a folder which contains `ArchiveSection` classes inside the Model folder, how should I name it?

- Model/ArchiveSections/
- Model/ArchiveSection/
- Model/archive_sections/

** I am using Symfony 2.3.*

Comment: For the lowercase, I'm guessing it implies a folder NOT containing classes. As for the plurals and that 'Default', well, good question.

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/bundles.html#bundle-directory-structure) talking about bundle directory structure.

I would say just keep in mind that the `Resources` directory structure must follow the standards to get some automatic registration of view paths and translations files in the kernel. The same applies to the `Command` directory.

For the rest it's how you want it to be, just know that the directory structure should repeat the symfony components structure to keep logic and readability (a `Twig` directory for creating twig extensions or functions, a `Serializer` directory to hold custom normalizers...).

This is relevant to have a good **directory structure** as it defines your classes **namespace structure**.

Comment: Hello @Heah, I know that I can name my folders the way I want (exept those which must follow the "convention over configuration" principles), my question was more about the Symfony standard structure (if there's one), do you know why they are named like this? Thanks.

Comment: It's in my answer, basically to match the components structure in symfony code source.

Comment: There is actually a usage of both `Test` and `Tests`, first for specific test classes used in the second.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strictly rules for structure and architecture directory in symfony framework. But exist best practices and standard convention.

In your case, there is nothing issue and you can do what do you want.
It seems that underscore in name directory is not very standard convention but not mandatory.

For question deal with singular or plurial it seems that is unanswered convention from symfony developers. Example : Me I name my service directory with plurial like this 'services' and all my code run perfectly with this name.